# making an SP.UI print dialog

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, development, modal-dialog, printing, sp.ui

I'm thinking of adding a print button to my list ribbon , the minute I click on this button a print dialog appears showing the list of the available printers on my computer.
so this printdialog i was intending to do it in my custom element of the button :

```
<CustomAction Id="Ribbon.Library.PROGED"
            Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
            RegistrationId="10999"
            RegistrationType="List">
<CommandUIExtension>
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Library.Groups._children">
      <Group Id="Ribbon.Library.PRO"
             Title="PROGED"
             Template="Ribbon.Templates.Flexible2"
             Sequence="10000">
        <Controls Id="Ribbon.Library.PRO.Controls">
          <Button Id="Ribbon.Library.PRO.PrintAllFiles"
                  Command="PrintAllFiles"
                  Image32by32="_layouts/images/PRO.Ribbon/logopro_32.png"
                  LabelText="Print All Files"
                  TemplateAlias="o1"></Button>
        </Controls>
      </Group>
    </CommandUIDefinition>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Library.Scaling._children">
      <MaxSize Id="Ribbon.Library.PROGED.Scaling.MaxSize"
               GroupId="Ribbon.Library.PRO"
               Size="LargeLarge" />
    </CommandUIDefinition>
  </CommandUIDefinitions>
  <CommandUIHandlers>
    <CommandUIHandler Command="PrintAllFiles"
                     CommandAction="javascript:function CallDETCustomDialog('PrintAllFiles',dialogResult, returnValue)
                                  {
                                  SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);
                                  }
                                  var options = {
                                  url: '{SiteUrl}' + '/_layouts/YBBEST/TitleRename.aspx?List={ListId}&amp;ID={ItemId}',
                                  title: 'Rename title',
                                  allowMaximize: false,
                                  showClose: true,
                                  width: 500,
                                  height: 300,
                                  dialogReturnValueCallback: CallDETCustomDialog };
                                  SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);"/>

  </CommandUIHandlers>

</CommandUIExtension>
```

It's just I didn't know how to translate this .net regular printing dialog to javascript SP.UI printing dialog:

```
    public void printall(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDialog pd  = new PrintDialog();
        pd.PrinterSettings = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();
        this.Close();
        pd.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. Are you looking for `CommandAction="javascript: window.print()"` or is that what you already have?

Comment: no that will print the current window , instead I want to print a selected file when I'm having a collection of printers, so I need a printdialog as the same of .net to choose my printer, i just didn't know how to call it in sharepoint

Comment: As far as I know you can only show the print dialog that the browser support. But if you want to force a print dialog you could always add a JavaScript to **AdditionalPageHead** and have this check for something in the URL onload (querystring like `?output=print` or a hash `#print`, and if this is given trigger window.print. Example with jQuery: `$(function(){window.location.hash.match(/print/) && window.print()})`

Comment: What you're trying to do is not possible in Javascript, as it only has access to the browser capabilities, and cannot access system resources like printers. Instead, you could add a Silverlight control to your page that [handles the print functionality](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/75468/Silverlight-4-Printing-Functionality), and pass the file contents to it.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you isolate the issue away from SharePoint and post on StackOverflow you'll get a bigger response. If I'm right in thinking you want to print a selection using javascript - I can propose a 'dirty' way of achieving this - simply construct a page from the selection by writing the selection to a fully constructed html page (so just the selected div, for example, inside body tags inside html tags) and print that whole page.